# how to achive localization in database level?

Tags: database, localization, globalization

How do I store **data into a textbox or label in different languages like french,hindi** etc and *store them in database*.

I have done localization in UI level but how to do that in DATABASE level.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

Either you add a column for every language into your database table, e.g. product_de, product_en, etc.

Or:

You add a translation table like this:

```
id | language | text
```

And just add all the translations for a product to this table. It's a bit more complex than the first solution, but easier to add new languages. But if you already know which languages you need and this will not change, I would go with the first solution.